# LibGDX Tablelayout Menu does not show

Tags: java, user-interface, opengl-es, libgdx, android-tablelayout

I'm writing a new program in LibGDX handling Backgroundtextures and have just begun to implement the screens. But when I test it, it just shows me a black cleared screen with the given resolution. 
I call the screen with the setScreen(screen)- Method in an implemented Game class.

So here is the code:

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen{
Table table;
Stage stage;
TextButton button;
TextField textField;
Texture texture;
Pic2Box2d game;

public MenuScreen(Pic2Box2d gameH)
{
    this.game = gameH;
    stage = new Stage(0, 0, true);
    table = new Table();
}
public void create()
{
    final TextFieldStyle fieldStyle = new TextFieldStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE, new BitmapFont(), Color.GRAY, null, null, null);
    textField = new TextField("path", fieldStyle);
    final TextButtonStyle buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    buttonStyle.font = new BitmapFont();
    buttonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
    buttonStyle.pressedOffsetY = 1f;
    buttonStyle.downFontColor = new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f);
    button = new TextButton("Übernehmen", buttonStyle); 
    button.setClickListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void click(Actor actor, float x, float y) {
            if(textField.getText() != "" && textField.getText() != "path")
            {
            texture = new Texture(textField.getText());
            game.setScreen(new Workscreen(texture));
            }
        }
    });
    table.row();
    table.add(textField);
    table.add(button);
    stage.addActor(table);
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@idaNakav is correct about using *show()* and setting the *Stage* dimensions. However, that will still give you a black screen because your table doesn't have any size. Try changing your *show()* code to include *table.setFillParent(true)*.

It should look something like this (code based on the example that you provided).

```
@Override
public void show() {
    final TextFieldStyle fieldStyle = new TextFieldStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE, null, null, null);
    textField = new TextField("path", fieldStyle);
    final TextButtonStyle buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    buttonStyle.font = new BitmapFont();
    buttonStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;
    buttonStyle.pressedOffsetY = 1f;
    buttonStyle.downFontColor = new Color(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f);
    button = new TextButton("Übernehmen", buttonStyle);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            if (textField.getText() != "" && textField.getText() != "path") {
                texture = new Texture(textField.getText());
                game.setScreen(new Workscreen(texture));
            }
        }
    });


    table.row();
    table.add(textField);
    table.add(button);

    // Make the table fill the stage.
    table.setFillParent(true);

    stage.addActor(table);
}
```

Comment: Thats it... in addition to the forgetting of the "@Override" statement in my "game"-class :D

Answer (score 1):

When screen is becoming the current screen [show](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html#show%28%29) method is called (not create like in your case), try changing your create method to show

also you are init the stage wrong , you should send it width and height , you sent 0,0 
try something like

```
stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),false);
```

Comment: black screen as well...this isn't the solution :/

Comment: it also didn't worked. The last boolean is the boolean for "stretch" so it does not matter, what I type in first, it will always be stretched to the screen size...

Comment: now I added a System.out.print to the show method. It only gets called once... render gets called multiple times, maybe thats the fault... I try to change the create() method to the show() method and the show() method to render()...

Comment: its ok , show should be called once and render should be called very often , and i was talking about the first two parameters of the Stage constructor.. if you did changed them like i told you and you still get black screen , try also to debugging the Table itself calling table.debug(); and Table.drawDebug(stage);